# I have to push twice for that DIV to open

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm using a JavaScript code that it suppose to show a hidden DIV, but somehow i have to push twice in order for that DIV to appear.

JavaScript code:

```
    function AddComp() {
    HideComp();


    $("#Add-Com").click(function () {
        $("#hide").toggle("fast", function () {

            $('#hide').css({ visibility: "visible", height: "auto" });
        });
    });
    var a = document.getElementById("divSave");
    a.onclick = InsertComp; 
}

function HideComp() { 
  $('#hide').css({ visibility: "hidden", height: "0" }); 
  $("#Name").val(""); 
  $("#Address").val(""); 
  $("#Email").val(""); 
}
```

in HTML i have this:

```
<div id="Add-Com" onclick="AddCom()">
        <span>Add Company</span></div>
<div id="hide" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px;"> .....the code
```

Can anyone help me?

The default status is hidden. I want want to toggle it by clicking once.
Thanks

Comment: What does HideComp() do?

Comment: Is InsertComp and AddComp the same thing?

Comment: You're referencing `#AddCom` in the JS but the id of the div is `Add-Com`.

Comment: function HideComp() {
        $('#hide').css({ visibility: "hidden", height: "0" });
        $("#Name").val("");
        $("#Address").val("");
        $("#Email").val("");
    }

Comment: No esrange. That are dif. fuctions

Comment: Add-Com is the div where i have the button for Add Company

Comment: You're binding the `click` handler inside the `AddComp` function.  So you need to click once to enable the click handler, then a second time to run it.

Comment: @Mike For readability, please add the `HideComp` code in an edit to the question.  Also, please show where the element with the ID `AddCom` is defined (which is referenced in your jQuery code). You currently only show us an HTML element with the ID `Add-Com`.

Comment: So how i can do it in 1 click Rocket?

Comment: apsillers> i did. I forgot "-" when i translated into english my function.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  This code makes very little sense.  The `Add-Com` button calls `AddComp`, which calls `HideComp` and also binds another click handler to `Add-Com`.  Then the 2nd click on `Add-Com` calls *both* click handlers, thus hiding and unhiding the `hide` div.  What exactly do you want to achieve?  Do you want the `Add-Com` to hide the hidden div?  Show it?  Toggle it?

Comment: The default status is hidden. I want want to toggle it by clicking once.

Comment: if ($("#hide").is(":visible"))
            $("#hide").hide();
        else
            $("#hide").toggle("slow", function () {
        $('#hide').css({ visibility: "visible", height: "auto" });

It seems that this do the trick the way I want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ($("#hide").is(":visible")) $("#hide").hide(); 
else $("#hide").toggle("slow", function () 
{ $('#hide').css({ visibility: "visible", height: "auto" });
```

It seems that this do the trick the way I want it